# Half lap joints with Dremell 231 Shaper/Router Table

Tags: joinery

I'm trying to make half lap joints using Dremell 231 Shaper/Router Table.
I need to cut away 5 mm depth  40x40 mm from a 10 x 40 mm wood rood (450mm length)
[image]

However, I'm unable to keep a consistent depth, and straight margin. 
What would be the appropriate technique to be used for that ? What other tools should I use ?

This is the "router table" I have:

[image]

Additional information: wood is beech.

I'm trying to make a frame that it's going to be embedded in a drywall, with a lip that will be flush with the drywall, so the joins need to be precise.

[image: Drywall and joins]

Answer (score 1):

Typically half-laps are cut with a saw followed if necessary by a plane or chisel to fine-tune, not a router. The wrong power tool is not an improvement over the right hand tool.

Having said that, getting an even router cut over a large area is a matter of consistent handling, consistent pressure, etc. Wood is flexible; you need to keep it from moving and/or make sure the tool moves with it.  That may need improved technique; it may need feather boards, it may need a jig, depending on size of the work piece and exactly what you are doing.